# Выбор нескольких дат на Календаре

Tags: java, android, material-design

Я использую  библиотеку [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)
, и у меня два TextView (Откуда - Куда)... Так вот при нажатии на "Откуда", должен открыться диалоговое окно с календарем и там выбираю одну дату. Потом при открытии "Куда", предыдущая выбранная дата должна отображаться, то есть две даты выбираются. У меня пока для каждого textView по диалогу... Просто мне кажется это неправильный подход.

Так вот хотел спросить, как использовать для обоих TextView один Диалог и при этом получать два результата? Где именно копать?

Comment: Путешествовать во времени собрались?:)

Comment: )) Нет просто внутри диалога еще и другие данные добавлю)

Comment: Сейчас постараюсь ответ накатать

Comment: Жду............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте локальную `boolean` переменную, назовите её, скажем, `isFrom = false`.

При клике на кнопку/вьюшку, которая вызывается диалог для "откуда" присваивайте Вашей булевой переменной значение `true`. Для диалога "Куда", соответственно `false` устанавливайте обратно.

По идее Dialog у Вас открывается примерно таким способом:

```
private void showDatePickerDialog() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                CreateEventActivity.this,
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
        dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
    }
```

Далее перекрываем `onDateSet`, в котором и будем смотреть в какое текстовое поле вставить значение

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String month = String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1);
        String day = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
        if (isFrom)
           fromTextView.setText(day + "." + (month) + "." + year);
        else
           whereTextView.setText(day + "." + (month) + "." + year);
        showTimePickerDialog();
    }
```

Comment: удалите эту строчку, пример я брал из своего кода, этот метод вызывал у меня диалог с выбором времени

Comment: Спасибо заработало, извините, еще один момент,  как первую выбранную дату выделить. То есть чтоб пользователь видел выбранную уже дату...

Comment: не совсем понял, чтобы он видел дату где?

Comment: На календаре... Чтоб дата выбранная выделялась

Comment: Cделайте calendar локальным, и при установке "Куда" в onDateSet меняйте его с помощью calendar.set(year, month, day). Если же нажато "откуда", то присваивайте ему Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: Не получилось(. Ладно спасибо вам  большое!